# Multiple timers, same handler? MultiThreading, Server requests

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, events, timer

I am trying to make a program that will test a small server. 
The task is to make cyclic readings at some intervals.
For this, I thought to create separate timers (each one with its own interval), but on the Tick event, to have same handler.

Some code:

```
        If testStarted Then

                    Dim timer As New CustomTimer(tempCyclicReading.ReadInterval)
                    timer.AssignedNodeId = tempCyclicReading.NodeId
                    timer.DisplayName = tempCyclicReading.DisplayName
                    AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf CyclicReadingTimer_Tick
                    timer.Enabled = True

                    cyclicReadingTimers.Add(timer)

                End If



 Private Sub CyclicReadingTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim obj As CustomTimer = TryCast(sender, CustomTimer)

        Dim info As DataValue = ServerObj.ReadValue(tEO.Session, obj.AssignedNodeId)

        Dim temp As String = ""
        temp &= "      Cyclic reading: "
        temp &= "ItemName: " & obj.DisplayName & ", "
        temp &= "Value: " & CStr(info.Value) & ", "

        LogInBox(rtbLiveData, Color.ForestGreen, temp)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Utils.ReadException(ex)
        logger.Error("Error when ticking  cycling reading timer!" & vbCrLf & Utils.ReadException(ex))
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now I have some questions:

1. Is it ok to have same handler for all timers? What happens if 2 or timers will call the function ServerObj.ReadValue (which connects to the server and read a value from a node) ? I know that each timer is created in each own thread. BUt when the tick event happens, and the handler function is called, is a new instance (corresponding to each timer) of the handler, created ?
2. DO I need to provide a lock mechanism or the server will handle this itself?
3. I also have a LogInBox function, that writes some results in a richtexbox. Again, does the richtextBox have a buffer or a queue and knows to prioritize and server each call to display data?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You could have just one thread running with a datatime indicating the next execution time. And execute the method when the execution time is pass. That way, the method wouldn't run twice at the same time.

Comment: Yes, but somehow, I might need to run the method twice, or 3 times at the same time. The purpose is to test the server. I just need to be sure to handle this correctly in the code. 
The cyclic reads are independent one from another

Comment: ah ok. In that case, if you have shared resource that are written into then you will need a lock unless the object is specifically said to be thread safe.